# Suspend Camel consumer when significant number of messages consecutively fail

Tags: apache-camel

I would like to **suspend a Camel Kafka consumer** (i.e. the route) **based on the processing result of the last messages**. For example when the 10 last completed messages were failed with the same error, I would like to suspend consuming messages instead of sending thousands of messages to the error topic.

I found that [RoutePolicies](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/route-policy.html) like [ThrottlingInflightRoutePolicy](https://github.com/lburgazzoli/apache-camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/impl/ThrottlingInflightRoutePolicy.java) are able to suspend a route based on current inflight exchanges by accessing an InflightRepository.

So my question boils down to: is there also a **facility to look back on the last `n` completed messages** of a route? I think this would allow me to implement a RoutePolicy for my case.

Or, if not, can I build this facility myself by simply build a collection of processing summaries of the last few exchanges in an instance field of the RoutePolicy?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah there is no built-in route policy for that. We have as you say for throttling, and there is also for cron like scheduling.

So you can build your own, and keep a window of the last N messages and keep track of how many have failed, and then suspend when you hit that threshold.

Mind that what about resuming again? Should that be automated, eg after 5 minutes then try again. Otherwise its a manual step to make the consumer resume again.

Comment: Is it ok to keep the processing results of the last few Exchanges in an instance field of the RoutePolicy? And do I need to take care about thread-safety?

Comment: You can use RoutePolicyFactory to create either a shared a new policy per route. And yes if the route has concurrent consumers then you can have multiple threads into the policy. So the counters can be atomic (if you really care to be 100% accurate) or basic int/long primitives are good enough if in some rare high cocurrency you can get a lost update.